# Child windows resize at run-time despite explicitly setting sizes

Tags: c#, wpf

The main window of my application is fine and looks as it does in the designer. Any child windows will resize (see below) despite my explicitly setting size and minimum/maximum size.

[image: http://s3.postimg.org/6si9t4sxf/asdf.png]

```
<Window <!-- Irrelevant Stuff -->
        Title="Settings" 
        Height="165" Width="300" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        MinWidth="300" MinHeight="165" 
        MaxWidth="300" MaxHeight="165">
    <Grid>

        <!-- Controls -->

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

There is one way that I can get the window to look as it does in the designer, but why do I need to do this only for child windows?

```
<Window <!-- Irrelevant Stuff -->
        Title="Settings" 
        Height="165" Width="300" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid MinWidth="300" MinHeight="165" MaxWidth="300" MaxHeight="165">

        <!-- Controls -->

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The above will give the desired window where the left and bottom margins remain at 10 pixels but again, why do I need to do this for child windows and not the main window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `SizeToContent` to `WidthAndHeight` which means the `Window` will automatically resize on both width and height to fit its content.

Set `SizeToContent` to `Manual` to stop it automatically resizing.

Comment: No, the bottom bit of code gives me what I want, the above bit of code (the code without SizeToContent) does not. I don't know why though. I would suggest the same as you to anyone else, but I'm telling you that the below works for me. But I think the top should work too.